# does BIT fill unused space past 1 byte?

Tags: mysql, bit, diskspace, variable-length, space-efficiency

My tables will probably have very large row lengths.  If I'm reading correctly, a `BIGINT` with a value of `1` will take up the full 8 bytes.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html

This seems horribly inefficient.

Does a `BIT` act the same way, or is it a variable length hybrid?  I'm aware that using less than 1 full byte will still consume 1 byte of disk space except when there are other `BIT`s, for example, 8 `BIT 1` columns will only take 1 byte if I'm reading correctly.

In other words, if I have a `BIT 41` with no other `BIT` columns, will a row with `0` for that column consume 1 byte or the full 6 bytes as opposed to 2^41-1 which will of course take up the full 41 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-type.html), it looks like you're out of luck: a bit will always be the size you specified it to be. In fact, [it will most likely be larger.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html) You could consider serializing your bits into a BLOB field, as they *are* variable-length.

Comment: The key part from the second link is this: "An exception to this rule is the BIT type, which is not 4-byte aligned. In MySQL Cluster tables, a BIT(M) column takes M bits of storage space. However, if a table definition contains 1 or more BIT columns (up to 32 BIT columns), then NDBCLUSTER reserves 4 bytes (32 bits) per row for these. If a table definition contains more than 32 BIT columns (up to 64 such columns), then NDBCLUSTER reserves 8 bytes (that is, 64 bits) per row."